# Creating the onvif compliance camera using the GStreamer Pipeline

Tags: gstreamer, onvif, gstreamer-1.0

I have a camera and I am streaming the video data using the GStreamer. With below pipeline.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e camerasrc ! video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8554
```

Now I would like to make the streaming ONVIF compliance. How I can do it with Gstreamer?

Comment: some example code: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/master/tests/examples/rtsp/test-onvif.c

Answer (score 2):

GStreamer has support for ONVIF. Unfortunately it is not just as easy as running a pipeline with gst-launch, you should implement an RTSP server by using the [gst-rtsp-server](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server).